# httpd (apache) won't accept (ignores) changes to vhost.conf

Tags: django, mediatemple

I'm not really used to using plesk, but I am familiar with apache. I am trying to host a django site on a server that is hosting another website. The guy who set all this up is long gone... So I edited /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/conf/vhost.conf and added a new location tag under one that is currently running. Then I reset plesk/apache with the following commands (none of the methods have any affect).

```
# /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng -a -v

# /etc/init.d/psa stop
# /etc/init.d/psa start

# /etc/init.d/httpd/stop
# /etc/init.d/httpd/start
```

None of these return any errors or warnings or anything! So to trouble shoot this decided to change the other location and see if it took root. Then I restarted plesk/httpd and once again, no visible changes occurred. The changes I made didn't affect anything. I'm at a loss on how to trouble shoot this so anything would help. Here's the code from vhost.conf although I doubt it is the problem:

```
#This was changed to "<Location /test/>" but the page still loaded on /pyrview
<Location /pyrview/> 
  AddHandler mod_python .py
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.py
  PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
  SetEnv MATPLOTLIBRC "/home/apache/.matplotlib"
  PythonPath "['/var/www/vhosts/domainname.org/httpdocs/pyrview/'] + sys.path"
  PythonDebug On
</Location>

#Here is the location I added
<Location /fish/>
  SetHandler python-program
  PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
  SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE fish.settings
  PythonDebug On
  PythonInterpreter fish
</Location>

<Location /fish/media>
  SetHandler None
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart Apache on your server.

Likely, you'll want to run `/sbin/apachectl graceful` (or similar path).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to run this before `apachectl graceful`:

```
/path/to/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=mt-example.com
```

I found this question looking for help with trying to get Django running with mod_wsgi. This site helped me: http://webmanufactory.blogspot.com/2009/06/last-post-about-mediatemple-dv-and.html

He also says to use `service httpd graceful` which is good if `apachectl` isn't there for some reason.